# Move class div up in DOM with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, dom

I'm trying to move a class div (i.e. 'topbar') out of its container and above a div with id (i.e. 'body'). Would this be possible with JavaScript?

Tried something like this without luck:

```
  document.getElementsByClassName('topbar').appendChild(document.getElementsById('body'));
```

Updating the question for better understanding. I want to move topbar above the body div.

The html:

```
<div id="body"> 
<div class="random"> </div> 
<div class="random"> </div> 
<div class="topbar"> </div> 
</div>
```

Comment: you are trying to append the document body. can you post your full code and explain what you are trying to do

Comment: Try to explain better

Comment: Do you want to insert the "topbar" div above "body" div?

Comment: Yes thats correct. updated the question.

Answer (score 1):

something like this?

```js
var container = document.getElementById('container');
var content1 = document.getElementById('content1');
var subContainer = document.getElementById('subContainer');
var body = document.body;
var content2 = document.getElementById('content2');
container.insertBefore(content1, subContainer);
body.insertBefore(content2, container);
```

```css
#container {
    padding:10px;
    background-color: lightgray;
}
#subContainer {
    border: 1px solid black;
    background-color: gray;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="container">
    <div id="subContainer">
      <div id="content1">
        Content 1 here blah blah blah
      </div>
      <div id="content2">
        Content 2 here blah blah blah
      </div>
      <div id="content3">
        Content 3 here blah blah blah
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Working with just Id´s is something I managed to do. But I wanted to move a class div outside it´s container (div id) and above it.

Comment: @InfotheekSE, check my edited post, is that what you're looking for?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you a trying to move the `topbar` element to be directly before and element with the class `body`. This can be achieved using the `insertBefore()` method: [JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/jrulle/an5nqcy6/)

```
window.onload = function () {

  //find the element to insert before and then get its parent element
  var beforeElement = document.getElementById('body');
  var parentElement = beforeElement.parentNode;

  //find the element we want to move
  //you need the array syntax because 'getElementsByClassName' returns an array of matching elements (even if there is only one match)
  var moveElement = document.getElementsByClassName('topbar')[0];

  //insert the moveElement into the parentElement before the theFirstChild
  parentElement.insertBefore(moveElement, beforeElement);

};
```

**Note:** since this code accesses and manipulated the DOM, you need to wrap this whole block in a `window.onload = function () { ...script goes here... };` to ensure the DOM has loaded before the script runs.
[insertBefore() method reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.insertBefore#Example2)

Comment: He didn't mentioned about where he want to put the topbar.....as a first child of "body" or just above "body"?
Answering such unclear question encourages spoon feeding...

Comment: Close! This placed the div below the target id. I want it to be placed above. @JRulle

Comment: Hmm that didnt work. The div with the id "body" is the first div in the dom, Before this its only a body tag. Does it need a parent element to work? Thanks for the help!

Comment: It should work because it will treat the `<body>` as the parent element. Here is a functional [**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/jrulle/an5nqcy6/) demonstrating the working code. I also simplified the above to be a singular answer rather than a series of edits.